# Fatal Error with Doctrine while using generate.php

Tags: php, doctrine, yaml

I'm working on the Doctrine tutorial at http://www.Doctrine-project.org/ and I receive a fatal error when I try to run my generate.php script which makes my models and makes tables in the database:

```
Fatal error: Class 'BaseCharity' not found in ...\models\Charity.php on line 14
```

generate.php:

```
require_once('bootstrap.php');
Doctrine_Core::dropDatabases();
Doctrine_Core::createDatabases();
Doctrine_Core::generateModelsFromYaml('schema.yml', 'models');
Doctrine_Core::createTablesFromModels('models');
```

and schema.yml

```
Charity:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    active:
      type: boolean
      default: '1'
    owed: decimal(32,2)
    totalPayed: decimal(32,2)
    name: string(255)
    website: string(255)
    description: text
    icon: string(255)
```

I am quite stumped by this, I can get it to correctly create other tables that are very similar or much more complicated then this one.  I've tried rewriting it as well.  I really have no clue where this error is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the models with the autoloader provided by Doctrine. No need to use any Iterators or what so ever

```
Doctrine::loadModels('path/to/your/models');
```

You can of course use it sevaral times:

```
Doctrine::loadModels('path/to/your/models/generated'); 
Doctrine::loadModels('path/to/your/models/custom');    
Doctrine::loadModels('path/to/your/models');
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DC-344

> Hi, I've stumbled upon the same
>   problem and I think I know where the
>   issue is.
>
> So
>   Doctrine_Core::createTablesFromModels()
>   calls Doctrine_Export::exportSchema()
>   which in turn calls
>   Doctrine_Core::loadModels().
>
> Doctrine_Core::loadModels() uses
>   RecursiveIteratorIterator and iterates
>   over all found files.
>
> Now I think the order of files
>   returned by RecursiveIteratorIterator
>   is not always the same (depends on OS,
>   filenames and cosmic radiation ), but
>   the most important thing here is that
>   class files from 'modules/generated'
>   directory (as in examples) ARE NOT
>   included before subclasses derived
>   from generated classes. This means
>   that Doctrine_Core::autoload() fails
>   to load classes from
>   'modules/generated' directory, exactly
>   this check fails:
>
> if (0 !== stripos($className,
>   'Doctrine_') ||
>   class_exists($className, false) ||
>   interface_exists($className, false))
>
> as base class is not starting with
>   'Doctrine_' and is not yet loaded.
>
> To fix it properly the algorithm for
>   loading modules must be changed to
>   first include 'modules/generated'
>   classes and then rest of classes. I am
>   not sure but maybe Core::autoload()
>   might be changed to include base
>   classes properly.
>
> QUICK WORKAROUND: As a quick
>   workaround I've changed parameters in
>   call to createTablesFromModels() to:
>
> Doctrine_Core::createTablesFromModels(array('models/generated','models'));
>
> as createTablesFromModels() can accept
>   array of directories.
>
> Hope this helps you, please let me
>   know if you need any more information.
>   Thanks!