# Doctrine dsn error with generate.php file

Tags: php, doctrine, yaml

I have been working on the introduction on the link below and have been able to complete previous steps but when it comes to running the generate.php file I get an error about the dsn. Is there missing steps that was ommited about changing the dsn?
http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/introduction-to-models/en#introduction-to-models

```
-----------------------------------
error output
-----------------------------------
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Connection_Exception' with message 'You must create your Doctrine_Connection by using a valid Doctrine style dsn in order to use the create/drop database functionality' in /Users/sone/sources/doctrine1.2/doctrine_test/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php:1460
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/sone/sources/doctrine1.2/doctrine_test/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Manager.php(707): Doctrine_Connection->dropDatabase()
#1 /Users/sone/sources/doctrine1.2/doctrine_test/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Core.php(972): Doctrine_Manager->dropDatabases(Array)
#2 /Users/sone/sources/doctrine1.2/doctrine_test/generate.php(8): Doctrine_Core::dropDatabases()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /Users/sone/sources/doctrine1.2/doctrine_test/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php on line 1460
-----------------------------------
```

[Fatal Error with Doctrine while using generate.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311751/fatal-error-with-doctrine-while-using-generate-php)

I saw a similar issue (link above) with the generate.php file here but the solution offered and error are slight different and don't work in my case. Changing the dsn string to
$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection('mysql://sonint99:C2sHF9Zxq3ULXCTV@127.0.0.1/doctrine'); does not work either. I get this error now.

si2:doctrine_test sone$ php generate.php

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Manager_Exception' with message 'Unknown connection: doctrine' in /Users/sone/sources/doctrine1.2/doctrine_test/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Manager.php:512
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/sone/sources/doctrine1.2/doctrine_test/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Manager.php(554): Doctrine_Manager->getConnection('doctrine')
#1 /Users/sone/sources/doctrine1.2/doctrine_test/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Export.php(1107): Doctrine_Manager->getConnectionForComponent('Test')
#2 /Users/sone/sources/doctrine1.2/doctrine_test/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Export.php(1205): Doctrine_Export->exportSortedClassesSql(Array)
#3 /Users/sone/sources/doctrine1.2/doctrine_test/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Export.php(1100): Doctrine_Export->exportClasses(Array)
#4 /Users/sone/sources/doctrine1.2/doctrine_test/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Core.php(894): Doctrine_Export->exportSchema('models')
#5 /Users/sone/sources/doctrine1.2/doctrine_test/generate.php(11): Doctrine_Core::createTablesFromModels('models')
#6 {main}
   in /Users/sone/sources/doctrine1.2/doctrine_test/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Manager.php on line 512
```

my boot strap

```
<?php
// bootstrap.php

/**
 * Bootstrap Doctrine.php, register autoloader specify
 * configuration attributes and load models.
 */

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine.php');

// ...
spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'autoload'));

// ...
$manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE, true);
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_AUTOLOAD_TABLE_CLASSES, true);

// Setting up DB connection
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=doctrine;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'sonint99';
$password = 'C2sHF9Zxq3ULXCTV';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection($dbh,'doctrine');
Doctrine_Core::loadModels('models');
//$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection('mysql://sonint99:C2sHF9Zxq3ULXCTV@127.0.0.1/doctrine');


generate.php

<?php


// generate.php

require_once('bootstrap.php');

Doctrine_Core::dropDatabases();
Doctrine_Core::createDatabases();
Doctrine_Core::generateModelsFromYaml('schema.yml', 'models');
Doctrine_Core::createTablesFromModels('models');
```

schema.yml

```
Test:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: test
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(8)
      autoincrement: true
      primary: true
    name:
      type: string()
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
User:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: user
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    first_name:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    last_name:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    username:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    password:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    type:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    is_active:
      type: integer(1)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: '1'
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    is_super_admin:
      type: integer(1)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: '0'
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    created_at:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    updated_at:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
```

Comment: You should change your password in any live system if it is the same as you wrote here. Allways remove real user/password data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Docs are rather strange because they mention PDO for the `::connection()` method. This method is not even used in the tutorials on the site ;)

A proper call with the connection could be like

```
$db['dsn'] = "mysql://user:password@localhost/database"; //use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1
$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection($db['dsn'], 'con_name');
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, you were correct about the incorrect use of PDO connection but it was used earlier here http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/introduction-to-connections/en and I skipped the changes later thinking it was ok to continue using it for my connection.